# Unsubscribe in a condition does not allow to subscribe in Angular RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, unsubscribe

Im having a service that show wornings,info, and error notifications.
Sometimes the notifications come very often. Lets say 20-30 in same time and im trying to avoid this thing by unsubscribing when a specifiv time interval happens.

After unsubscribe than its not anymore possibile to subscribe.

```js
  const locationsSubscription = this.messageService
      .getMessage()
      .pipe(timeInterval(), tap(console.log))
      .subscribe(message => {    
        if (message.interval < 500) {          
          locationsSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        else {
             switch (message.type){       
            case MessageType.Info:
              this.showInfo(message.text);
              break;
            case MessageType.Warning:
              this.showWarning(message..text);
              break;
            case MessageType.Error:
              this.showError(message.value);
              break;
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: why do you want to unsubscribe?

Comment: becouse have lots of notifications and dont want to show them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `debounceTime` or `throttleTime` to trigger warnings after some time is passed:

```
this.messageService
      .getMessage()
      .pipe(
         debounceTime(500) // to allow messages to trigger after 500ms of inactivity (idle)
         // throttleTime(500) // to allow only one message per 500ms (first or last)
      )
```